# Jssor Slider with 2 or more images in container

Tags: image, slider, containers, jssor

I've been using vertical Jssor Slider. After using, looking and editing the code, I still can't find out where to modify so that 2 or more images are displayed at once in Slider container. I downloaded Jssor Slider kit from

`http://www.jssor.com/download.html`

Answer (score 0):

All slides should be placed in `slides` container, by default, every slide inherits the size of `slides` container unless you explicitely specify `$SlideWidth`, `$SlideHeight` for slide.

So, please specify smaller `$SlideHeight`, then you have chance to display more than one slide in `slides` container.

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-arrange-layout-adjust-size.html